# Error: A compound literal of type not allowed

Tags: c, syntax-error, compound-literals

I have a structure containing pointers to callback functions like such:

```
typedef void    (*LOAD_CB)(resource* r);
typedef void    (*UNLOAD_CB)(resource* r);

typedef void    (*CREATE_CB)(void* i);
typedef void    (*DESTROY_CB)(void* i);

typedef struct /*_resman_callbacks*/ //<-- causes error
{
    LOAD_CB    load;
    UNLOAD_CB   unload;
    CREATE_CB  create;
    DESTROY_CB destroy;

} resman_callbacks;
```

I then initialize these functions at runtime and add them to a list containing other callbacks with a call to a function:

```
register_extension(".my_file_extension", &(/*error appears here*/resman_callbacks){load, unload, create, destroy});
```

This does not cause an error when my structure does not have a name (such as _resman_callbacks), however when a name is provided in the structure definition, my IDE shows an error "a compound literal of type "resman_callbacks" is not allowed". This does not cause any runtime issues, nor does it cause the code to fail compilation. Which leaves me with two questions

A) Is this something to be concerned about, considering that my code still functions?

B) Why is the structure having a name causing the error to appear?

My IDE is Visual Studio Express 2013.

Edit:
Added the declaration and implementation of register_extension, plus other relevant data.

```
//resman.h
void    register_extension(char* file_ext, resman_callbacks* cb);

//resmain.c
typedef struct
{
    char*                 ext; //extension associated with this resource
    resman_callbacks*     cb;  //structure containing callback functions

} registered_extension;

typedef struct
{
    registered_extension* reg_ext;  //list of registered extensions
    unsigned short        ext_ct;   //current number of registered extensions
    unsigned short        size;     //maximum number of registered extensions
} ext_manager;

static ext_manager extman;

void register_extension(char* ext, resman_callbacks* callbacks)
{
    if (extman.ext_ct == extman.size)
    {
        extman.size = extman.size * 2;
        extman.reg_ext = realloc(extman.reg_ext, extman.size);
    }

    *(extman.reg_ext + extman.ext_ct) = (registered_extension) { ext, callbacks };
    extman.ext_ct = extman.ext_ct + 1;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to show us **at least** the declaration (function signature) of `register_extension`.  Preferably the implementation as well.

Comment: @selbie Done. Sorry about that.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That's... Interesting. But wouldn't that cause this to throw a compile time error? Instead all I'm getting is a "syntax error" (squiggly line in the text editor) with no warnings, errors, or exceptions otherwise.

Comment: sorry, It has support since VS2013. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293.aspx

Comment: Probably not the problem (yet possibly may be): Identifiers beginning with an underscore are reserved for file-scope identifiers (also in the tag namespace). Maybe your IDE is confused by that reserved identifier…

Comment: @mafso i do wish that was the problem. I originally encountered the problem when the identifier did not have the underscore however. But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Splicing your snippets together (wrapping the `register_extension` call into a `main` function, adding missing declarations, including `<stdlib.h>`) this code compiles without warnings with gcc. It compiles for you. I can't see anything wrong with the line in question. The standard says, the constraints for the type in a compound literal are that it "shall specify a complete object type or an array of unknown size, but not a VLA type". The initilizer-list in a compound expression has the same restrictions as for initializers. Looks like a problem with your IDE.

Comment: Alright then. That's what I was kind of leaning towards. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have the following functions declared **before** you actually use them in your code:

```
void load(resource* r);
void unload(resource* r);
void create(void* i);
void destroy(void* i);
```

Try this:

```
resman_callbacks cb = {load, unload, create, destroy};
register_extension(".my_file_extension", &cb);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. That's what i was doing earlier, and it works. The method in my post currently doesn't not work, it just yields a phantom error that causes no problems at compile or runtime. My question is more a question of curiosity than it is necessity. Basically if what im doing is, for some reason, syntactically wrong, or if it's a problem with the IDE for some reason.